# TYPO3: Where is $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['environment'] defined?

Tags: typo3, sentry, typo3-9.x

In his [Sentry TYPO3 Integration](https://github.com/helhum/sentry-typo3/), Helmut Hummel defines the environment via `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['environment']` [here](https://github.com/helhum/sentry-typo3/blob/master/src/Sentry.php#L39).

I've never seen this TYPO3_CONF_VARS setting before and searching the TYPO3 core of TYPO3 9.5 I can't find it either.

Background to my question is, that the environment detection doesn't work for me with the Sentry TYPO3 Integration. I have defined the `TYPO3_CONTEXT` in my .htaccess file like this:

`SetEnvIf Host "ddev\.site" TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development/DDEV`

So the question is, do I just need to define `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['environment']` manually in my LocalConfiguration.php / AdditionalConfiguration.php or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define it manually, or dynamically based on application context.

The setting was introduced by the extension itself and is not provided, nor used, by TYPO3 itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you want to modify anything installation wide in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']`, it's put into the `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` file.

Some configurations, that are only relevant for extensions you might also find in those extensions `ext_localconf.php` files, but that's probably not what you need.

LocalConfiguration might work, but that one is generated and overwritten by the install tool.

As a side note: The default configuration can be found in `typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php`.